# Maya get vertex by position

Tags: python, maya

i'm new in python and i'm trying to make a script that get the nearest face by  a determinate postition. Anyone knows if there are already any function?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried in the question.

Comment: You've got a much higher chance of getting a usable answer if you give us some more detail and an example of what you've tried

Comment: I finally do this, but maya dont initiate now dont know why, it doesn't show any error message :/
I dont save the script cause it was done with the console in maya and it saves automatically somewhere, do you know where i can search? i tried already in the scripts folders in diferent locations but didnt find what i've done

Answer (score 1):

there is a node called closestPointOnMesh

```
nodeName = cmds.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')
```

it can return position, face, vertex

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you please specify how i get the position, face or vertex of the node created? or can you send me a link with a good documentation of that? thanks

Comment: you connect the matrice of both object and then you get the info with some getAttr .....

Comment: Thank you a lot! Maya crashes so i cant post what i've done to help other people. Do you know where i find the scripts done with the console? (i didnt save no one)

Comment: you can't that why people use some IDE to write script. Maya is quite annoying on this point

Comment: oh :/ I wish I had known before

Answer (score 0):

thats the solution i found for that:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

def getClosestFace(xPos, yPos, zPos, mesh):
    cmds.select(mesh)
    mel.eval("closestPointOn (1, 1)")
    cmds.select("cpConstraintIn")
    cmds.move(xPos,yPos,zPos)
    faceOutput = cmds.getAttr("closestPointOnMesh1.f")
    cmds.delete("cpConstraintIn")
    cmds.delete("cpConstraintPos")
    return mesh + ".f[" + str(faceOutput) + "]"
```

this is the same for other components like vertex or edges, only change the ".f".
But it seems if there are some components at the same distance of the initial position it chooses the closest component randomly?, or the end component of a list?